# Error running ghost on Windows 10

Tags: ghost

I installed ghost and ghost-CLI on Windows 10. When I run `ghost start` I get the error below. how to fix this? It seems related to the command to check file and folder permissions. Note that I'm running ghost in the D: drive.

By the way, if I run `ghost run` it works.

```
D:\onlinehelp>ghost start
Process manager 'systemd' will not run on this system, defaulting to 'local'
√ Checking current folder permissions
√ Validating config
× Checking folder permissions
× Checking file permissions
√ Checking memory availability
One or more errors occurred.

1) Checking folder permissions

Message: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "find ./ -type d ! -perm 775 ! -perm 755"
FIND: Parameter format not correct


Exit code: 2



2) Checking file permissions

Message: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "find ./  -type f ! -path "./versions/*" ! -perm 664 ! -perm 644"
File not found - ./
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - F
File not found - !
File not found - -PATH
File not found - !
File not found - -PERM
File not found - 664
File not found - !
File not found - -PERM
File not found - 644


Exit code: 1


Debug Information:
    OS: Microsoft Windows, v10.0.16299
    Node Version: v8.9.1
    Ghost-CLI Version: 1.7.2
    Environment: production
    Command: 'ghost start'

Additional log info available in: C:\Users\pablo\.ghost\logs\ghost-cli-debug-2018-05-01T16_58_30_857Z.log

Try running ghost doctor to check your system for known issues.

Please refer to https://docs.ghost.org/v1/docs/troubleshooting#section-cli-errors for troubleshooting.

D:\onlinehelp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an ideal solution but it worked for me.

Ghost uses linux's `find` command to check permissions, this command does not exist on windows (or at least the windows `find` command does not accept the same arguments.

I was pretty sure my permissions were fine, so I decided to bypass the check.

To do so, locate where ghost-cli is installed globally, in my case it was
`C:\Users\your-name-here\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ghost-cli`

In there, you want to find `lib\commands\doctor\checks\check-permissions.js`

you will notice a line that starts with
`return execa.shell(`

This is the line we want to avoid, to do so, we can return a result before it is run, in my case I added the line `return Promise.resolve();`

e.g.

```
return Promise.resolve();

return execa.shell(checkTypes[type].command, {maxBuffer: Infinity}).then((result) => {
...
```